# Unable to reach the adsense api documentation

Tags: google-ads-api

I have a problem reaching the docs under the link - https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/start. I'm getting the error "Service Unavailable" for several days now.

Did the docs move? Have somebody the same problem?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn off your ad blocker.,